Force required to prevent thermal expansion of rod | Double answer
The problem:
Q. Calculate the compressional force required to prevent the metallic rod of length l cm and cross-sectional area
A cm2 when heated through t degree C, from expanding along length wise. The Young's modulus of elasticity of the metal
is E and mean coefficient of linear expansion is alpha per degree Celsius
a) $EA\alpha t/(1-\alpha t)$
b) $EA\alpha t/(1+\alpha t)$
c) $EA\alpha t$
d) $El\alpha t$
My efforts:
type 1(my answer):
$$\frac{\Delta l}{l}= \alpha\, t  $$
we know $$E =\frac{ \frac{F}{A}}{\frac{\Delta l}{l}}  $$
$$ F= E A \frac{\Delta l}{l}=E\, A \,\alpha\,t  $$
type2(website/internet answer):
length of rod at $t$ degree $= l(1+\alpha t)$
change in length $(\Delta l)$, due to stress  $= -l\;\alpha\,t$
so similar to type 1, $E =(F/A) / (\Delta l/l)$, $F=EA(\Delta l/l)$, but this is :
$$F=EA \frac{((l \alpha t)}{(l (1 + \alpha t)))}=E A \frac{\alpha t} {(1+\alpha t)}$$
The term prevent means that the stress acts at starting when length of rod is l, the rod starts from length l and thermal expansion is prevented by stress,so type 1 should be correct. In type 2 rod is took to start in expanded state and then stress acts which doesn't look correct.  I am not sure about which answer is correct,but moreover, also the words 'mean coefficient of linear expansion' seem to signify something like maybe we should start with a rod half expanded? which brings in type 3..
So how should the thermal expansion concept be applied in such problem.

The $\alphs \Delta T$ in thee denominator of method 2 is considered neglgiible compared to the 1 , so, in linearized analysis, the two answers are equivalent.

@ChetMiller true, but lets assume that alpha t is not very small and negligible, else it would make the question meaningless

It by no means makes the question meaningless.  We know the material behavior only for small strains.  For large strains, you need to use large strain theory, in which the state of stress is a ;non-linear function of the deformation kinematics.

@redoc If the stress-strain relationship is assumed to be linear (which is most likely in your case since the thermal expansion is), then the second-order terms can be ignored and your answer is correct.

Consider the problem from first principles, and in course of resolving the problem apply any necessary assumptions if needed.
Consider problem in two stages.

The rod of length $\ell$ expands to $\ell + \Delta \ell$ due to a temperature rise of $\Delta T$ using the coefficient of thermal expansion $\alpha$
$$\Delta \ell = \ell (\alpha \Delta T) \tag{1} $$

The rod is compressed by $\Delta \ell$ due to a force $F$. Assuming linear stress strain in the region ( $\sigma = E\; \epsilon )$ we have the definition of stress as $$\sigma = \frac{F}{A} \tag{2}$$ and of strain $$ \epsilon = \frac{\Delta \ell^\star}{\ell^\star} \tag{3}$$
Note that $\ell^{\star}$ designates the starting length before the force is applied, which means $\ell^\star = \ell + \Delta \ell$, and $\Delta \ell^\star = \Delta \ell$
I am ignoring the positive and negative signs associated with forces and deflections for brevity. 
This results in the relationship $$F = E A \frac{\Delta \ell}{\ell+\Delta \ell} \tag{4}$$ and here we substitute (1) to get  $$\boxed{ F = A E \frac{ \alpha \Delta T}{1 + \alpha \Delta T} } \tag{5}$$


But do not disparage yourself because $ 1 + \alpha \Delta T \approx 1$ in real life for most materials.
The assumption you applied to get your answer is that the deflection $\Delta \ell$ due to thermal expansion happens at the same time as the application of force, which is actually a more realistic scenario.
In this case, $\ell^\star = \ell$, and $\Delta \ell^\star = \Delta \ell$ and you end up with
$$F = E A \frac{\Delta \ell}{\ell} \tag{6}$$ and here we substitute (1) to get  $$\boxed{ F = A E ( \alpha \Delta T)} \tag{7}$$
which is your correct answer also.
The difference here is with the underlying assumptions for the mechanics of the situation.
